# How to properly stop a multiprocessing process in FastAPI?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application that starts a multiprocessing process using the multiprocessing.Process module. The process listens for events pushed through a Redis pubsub channel. Here is the relevant code:

#### The subscribe function:

```py
def subscribe_stream():
    """
    Listens for event pushed through the Redis pubsub channel
    """
    while True:

        redis = connect_to_redis()

        event_stream = redis.pubsub()
        event_stream.subscribe("event_stream")

        for result in event_stream.listen():
            # DO ACTION
```

#### The FastAPI startup function:

```py
event_stream = multiprocessing.Process(target=subscribe_stream)


api = FastAPI(
    on_startup=[event_stream.start],
    on_shutdown=[event_stream.terminate],
```

#### The problem:

When I stop my FastAPI project the `event_stream.terminate` is called but I think it's ignored because of the While True loop. Does anyone has a solution to keep the subscribe stream open until the on_shutdown is called from FastAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you do that while True loop in order to redirect to Redis once it disconnects, but that will result in the Redis connection not closing properly once you try to terminate the process. You can remove the while True loop, and add a handler for closing the Redis connection on a terminate call. You also need to add an except statement that restarts the function if the Redis connection fails. This will look something like this:

```
def subscribe_stream():
"""
Listens for event pushed through the Redis pubsub channel
"""

try:

    redis = connect_to_redis()

    event_stream = redis.pubsub()
    event_stream.subscribe("event_stream")

    def before_exit(*args):
        event_stream.close()
        redis.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    signal(SIGTERM, before_exit)

    for result in event_stream.listen():
        # DO ACTION
except Exception as error:
    subscribe_stream()
```